How to use the Python API in C++ without adding Python to PATH?
I am embedding a Python interpreter inside a C++ application, but wish to keep this interpreter as isolated as possible from any other Python instances on an end-user's device.
As a result, I would like to be able to interface with the Python API without adding this "embedded" Python interpreter to the path - however my code keeps "hanging".
I believed that starting the interpreter in "isolated" mode, and providing my own PATH string would allow me to bypass any reliance on my device's environment variables but instead running my code results in no output. Not even from the standard C++ output commands.
The code I have created so far is shown below:
#include <iostream>
#include ".\\Python312\\include\\Python.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    std::cout << "Starting Python initialization..." << std::endl;

    //Initialize PyPreConfig for early configurations
    PyPreConfig preconfig;
    PyPreConfig_InitIsolatedConfig(&preconfig);  // Initialize for isolated configuration
    preconfig.isolated = 1;   // Enable isolated mode to prevent usage of environment variables

    // Apply the PyPreConfig settings
    PyStatus status = Py_PreInitialize(&preconfig);

    // Initialize PyConfig for detailed interpreter settings
    PyConfig config;
    PyConfig_InitPythonConfig(&config);  // Initialize to default Python configuration

    // Set the Python home directory
    PyConfig_SetString(&config, &config.home, L".\\Python312");
    
    // Set the Python executable path
    PyConfig_SetString(&config, &config.executable, L".\\Python312\\python.exe");

    // set the Python path
    Py_SetPath(L".\\Python312\\Lib;"
               L".Python312\\DLLs");

    // Initialize Python with the configuration
    status = Py_InitializeFromConfig(&config);
    if (PyStatus_Exception(status)) {
        PyErr_Print();  // Print any errors
        PyConfig_Clear(&config);  // Clear configuration on error
        std::cerr << "Failed to initialize Python interpreter with configuration!" << std::endl;
        Py_ExitStatusException(status);  // Exit on error
    }

    if (!Py_IsInitialized()) {
        std::cerr << "Python interpreter not initialized!" << std::endl;
        return 1;
    }

    std::cout << "Python initialized successfully." << std::endl;

    // Execute a simple Python command
    int result = PyRun_SimpleString("print('Hello from full Python installation!')");
    if (result != 0) {
        std::cerr << "Error executing Python code!" << std::endl;
        PyErr_Print();  // Print the Python error to the console
    }

    Py_Finalize();
    PyConfig_Clear(&config);

    std::cout << "Python finalized." << std::endl;
    return 0;
}


Any help on how to fix this (or at least how to get some kind of error message) would be greatly appreciated :)
BTW: when I add python to my PATH manually (through the Windows tool), the code runs fine.

Attach a debugger and find out which call is hanging.

I think you also need PyConfig_InitIsolatedConfig rather than the "non-isolated" version.

Are you running in the correct directory (given all the relative paths), and should there be a \\ inside L".Python312\\DLLs"?

Tried to compile with
g++ test_py.cpp -o testpy -L./Python312 -lpython312

& run, windows says it doesn't find python312.dll...
Copied the python312.dll on folder above (next to testpy.exe) and it works.
You must somehow provide with the library since you use it.
Maybe a .bat that adds the PATH before calling the exe and removes it afterwards could work for you?
set oldpath=%PATH%
set PATH=%PATH%;./python312
testpy.exe
set PATH=%oldpath%

An exe that starts the exe (or loads another, precompiled lib) with something like could also do
string path_s = "PATH=";
path_s += getenv("PATH");
path_s += ";./Pyhton12";
if (putenv(path_s.c_str()) != 0) {
    fprintf(stdout, "Error when adding python path : returning error 26.\n");
    return 26;
}
... call load your exe or compile your code as a lib to load there

BTW, test_py.cpp:37:15: warning: 'void Py_SetPath(const wchar_t*)' is deprecated
and take a look at python virtual environments (venv).
